# Problema al añadir columna a una tabla MySQL con PDO (Se añaden comillas en el nombre)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Estoy tratando de **añadir nuevas columnas a una tabla de base de datos**, pero tengo un problema y es que al añadir la columna, se añaden con 'comillas simples' en el nombre. **Así:**

```
| id | es | 'en' |
```

La nueva columna sería `'en'`, y se crea tal cual se muestra *(con las comillas)*.

**Código:**

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("ALTER TABLE `languages` ADD `:lang` LONGTEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL");
$stmt->bindParam(":lang", strtolower($_POST["lang"]));
$stmt->execute();
```

**Valor de las variables (con var_dump()):**

```
$_POST["lang"] // string(2) "EN"
strtolower($_POST['lang']) // string(2) "en"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pudieras dejarlo de este modo

Asigna a una variable lo que te llega por `POST`

```
$lenguaje = $_POST["lang"];
```

Posterior pasas de manera directa dicha variable a tu sentencia `ALTER` así dentro de las *backticks*

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("ALTER TABLE `languages` ADD `$lenguaje` LONGTEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL");
```

Posterior remueves el uso de `bindParam()` y solo invocas al método `execute()` de este modo

```
$stmt->execute();
```